# how can i increment a variable with an "if" in a django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to increment a variable with "if" in the Django template, I've already tried all the suggestions on this site, but none have solved my problem.
there is views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'home/index.html'
context_object_name = 'problemes'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context_data['problemes'] = Probleme.objects.all()
    context_data['commentaires'] = Commentaire.objects.all()
    return context_data


def get_queryset(self):
    result_list = self.get_context_data
    return result_list
```

and index.html

```
....
 {% for problem in problemes %}
                                        {% with number_comment= 0%}
                                        {% for comment in commentaires %}
                                        {% if comment.probleme.id == problem.id %}
                                        {% number_comment ++ %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}

                                    <tr data-status="pagado">
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="votes">
                                            <div class="mini-counts"><span title="74 votes">74</span></div>
                                            <div>votes</div>
                                        </div>


                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="status answered-accepted" title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer">
                                            <div class="mini-counts"><span title="2 answers">{{ number_comment }}</span></div>
                                            <div>answers</div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% endwith %}
                                        ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reference your `number_comment` directly as you have it in your index.html, you can use an `add` template tag to increment it. Of course this increments number only in template and doesn't save to the database.

```
{{ number_comment|add:"1" }}
```

Comment: Where do you get this number_comment from? Is a field of your Commentaire model? In this case you should access it with commment.number_comment.

Comment: no, is not a field of commentaire, it's a variable that I want to increment when I explore a list of items with a condition if something ... (with template)

Comment: any help, please!

Comment: But you should pass this variable to the template from the view. You can't instantiate variables within the template. You could of course do it with a JavaScript, but that is something completely different. You can for example instantiate the variable in you view like that context_data['number_comment'] = 0. And than my answer would work.

Comment: i fixed this problem by creatin a class Counter in my model with two functions "increment" and "set_to_zero", after i pass it in the context and use it in template, what you think is it good solution or not ?

Comment: If it's working the way you want, than it's definitely a good solution.